# Unable to get the date difference between two dates in php

Tags: php, datediff, date-difference

So I have the following code which have found somewhere else in SO to get the difference between the two dates.

```
 $datetime1 = new DateTime('2018-07-11');
 $datetime2 = new DateTime('2018-07-13');
 $diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

I don't have problem with that one for it works well, but when I try to apply it on my own, can't get the difference or the difference is 0.

```
 $datetime1 = new DateTime($date_today);//format is 2018-07-01, string format
 $datetime2 = new DateTime($date);//format is 2018-07-31, string format
 $diff= $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

 log::info($diff->format('%d'));
```

Output for this one is `0` which supposed to be `30`. Can you help me on this one, please?

Comment: This `2018-07-0` not being a valid date may be part of the issue, or is that just a bad comment

Comment: What date is this `2018-07-0`?

Comment: Nope, `DateTime` will change `2018-07-0` to `2018-06-30`

Comment: And where in the state of calendar, did you ever see a Zero'th of the month

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's just after February 31st, which PHP is also perfectly happy to roll over into the next month

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's just a typo. It should be `01`, thought I have already edited it.

Answer (score 1):

```
log::info($diff->format('%a'));
```

is the solution

See here in a php sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32bcea357af442f92a1875e1669af6f01973df6d

The `$diff` is a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object which has other [DateInterval::format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) parameters